# How to place the transfom origin point of element in center of the view port

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, panzoom

I'm trying to make a website where you can zoom and pan.
Currently I'm working with the [panzoom package](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom), but the user should be able to rotate the scene content around the center of their screen.

I know how the transform-origin property works but I can't seem to figure out how to change it relative to the view port.

[image: example]

Here is a JSFiddle I'm working on: https://jsfiddle.net/jsrhkom4/28/.

**HTML**

```
<div class="scene">
  <div class="scene__content">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/500">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/500">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/500">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/500">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="js-turn-left">Rotate left</div>
  <div class="js-turn-right">Rotate right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scene__content {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  max-width: fit-content;
  max-height: fit-content;
  
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  grid-row: auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  
  img {
    width: 100%;
    
    &:nth-child(1) {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    
    &:nth-child(2) {
      transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
    
    &:nth-child(3) {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
  }
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background-color:red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items:center;
  
  div {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    background-color: crimson;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
const el = document.querySelector('.scene');
const scene = panzoom(el, {
  maxZoom: 1.5,
  minZoom: 0.5,
  smoothScroll: true,
  bounds: true
});

const turnLeft = document.querySelector('.js-turn-left');
const turnRight = document.querySelector('.js-turn-right');
const content = document.querySelector('.scene__content');
let angle = 0;

turnLeft.addEventListener('click', () => {
    angle-=45;
    content.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
});
turnRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
    angle+=45;
    content.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jsrhkom4/28/show.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to rotate this image around the center of the screen - then why is it not displayed in the center in its normal state already? If the element is _not_ in the center, but you say you want to set the transform-origin to the center of the viewport … what would that even look like then? Would the image rotate on some sort of circular path then, like a planet around the sun …

Comment: Yes, eventually there would be more content on the page, so if the user navigates around and for example is reading an article, then presses the 'rotate' button, everything should rotate around the center of the user's screen so the article in this example doesn't move out of the screen.

Comment: So is this one article out of multiple on the same page then, and you want to rotate only this article; or is the whole page supposed to rotate?

Comment: I'll make a new JSFiddle to make it more clear

Comment: I have edited the JSFiddle and demo, the intention is for example if a user zooms in on the top right image and rotates the screen, the whole page should rotate around the center of the screen instead of the center of the scene content, so the user stays at the same point on the page

Comment: If you want the element to keep rotating around its own center point, then it makes little sense to set transform-origin to anything but center. Instead, you should add a `translate` to your transformation, that moves the element to the middle of the viewport. So you’ll have to get the element dimensions and its position relative to the viewport, and do the math to find the correct x/y offsets.

Comment: But the problem here is that I don’t know what object the user is rotating around, so it should always just rotate aroud the center of the user’s viewport. It could even be possible the user has zoomed out so the whole page is in viewport, but also zoomed in to an article to the bottom right of the page so everytime the users navigates through the page the transform origin point should be recalculated to the coordinates of the center of the screen relative to the scene content.

Comment: Somehow this is making less and less sense to me, the more “explanation” you are adding. So you always want to rotate the whole document then, not just individual elements on their own? Is the whole document identical with the “scene” here then, or will there be multiple of those? _“the transform origin point should be recalculated to the coordinates of the center of the screen relative to the scene content”_ - still unclear to me, what _point_ you actually want to rotate around then.

Comment: First of all thanks for trying to figure this out with me. Yes, the whole document will rotate every time. The 'scene' is the place where the users can navigate around in. The 'scene content' is the content (the images in this case) in that scene. If the user navigates and zooms to a specific image, I want the whole 'scene content' to rotate around the center of the view the user is currently at. There will be only one scene with one scene content where all the content will be placed in.

Comment: For example: if you zoom and navigate to the image in the top right and rotate, everything should rotate around the center of the view at that current time so that image stays in view and the other content rotates around that specific point.

Comment: _“if you zoom and navigate to the image”_ - by “navigate”, you simply mean scrolling the page, after the zoom? So whatever _is_ in the middle of the viewport right now, should become the point that the whole thing rotates around, when one of the button is clicked? Then you will probably have to go and look into the documentation of that panning library first of all, to see which methods/events can help you figure out what is currently in the center of the screen.

Comment: Yes, I mean scrolling the page, but as you see in the demo this is not a normal page where you scroll vertically, but you can scroll the X and Y axis. And i don't necessarily want to rotate around an object but whatever the coordinate is of the center of the viewport at that moment. I have read the documentation and there is a method that provides me to set the origin of the zooming action but I can't use this for the rotation center point.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, I have added an example image to the question, hope this makes everything clear!

Comment: The `getTransform` method allows you to get the current scaling factor, and x/y offset. So you will have to take that information, and set it into relation to the viewport. The fact that the initial size of your scene does not appear to be identical to the viewport, adds a level of complexity here.